# MySQL - Update and Select in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm updating a table like so...

```
Update table Set count = count + 1 Where id = xx Limit 1
```

How to get the value of count without querying the table again? Can it be done in one query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

No.

Update does not return a result set.
However you **can** get the count without having to query the **table**

```
UPDATE `table` SET count = @count:= count + 1 WHERE id = 'xx' LIMIT 1;

SELECT @count as LastUpdateCount;
```